# Way to assosiate new provision profile with old ipa

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-provisioning

We are developing an application for ipad.

Right now process is like the number of devices we have we are adding its device id in our developer account and generate a provision profile and add it in our xcode project and then we generate .ipa file. Then we deploy the app deploy-able file and the .ipa file to our Application Center (internal app store).

so my question is: whenever we have to add a new device we rebuild the whole project and deploy it again. Is there any way that we add the device and the new provision profile gets associate with the old .ipa without rebuilding the project again?

Comment: we actually use test flight which takes care of adding new devices, what does internal App Store mean ? is it a product or simply a page where you app gets installed via OTA ?

Comment: It's a web app you deploy the ipa to. Devices can then connect to a web page and install apps from this store. It is not really related to the question IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want is an Enterprise Distribution Profile.  It allows you to build the app once, without the need to specify each device in the development distribution profile.  It makes it much easier if you are constantly adding devices, or if you have more than the 100 that a development profile allows.

Here's more information: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not how device provisioning works with Apple.

To have your application work on a device, you need to add the device to your list of devices, and then you need to add the device to the provisioning profile. You then need to build the project in Xcode and make sure that the new provisioning file is deployed to the device via Xcode Organizer.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/provision_device_for_development-generic.html